# $ionicPlatform onHardwareBackButton runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an issue with the back button running more than once.

currently I'm in my "messages" $state, and if I press the back button the following code works as normal.

```
var messageIsClosed = true;

$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  handleBackButton();
})

var handleBackButton = function(){
  if(messageIsClosed){
    $state.go("dash");
  } else {
    messageIsClosed = false;
  }
}
```

however, if I go to another $state (say, "dash") and then return to "messages", pressing the back button will make the above code run twice. Then if I go back to "messages" again it runs 3 times, then 4. For each time I visit the "messages" view/controller the back button code will run an extra time

I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

The `onHardwareBackButton` will run multiple times and this is normal in your case. This is because you are registering the event every time you visit the messages state.

To avoid the multiple registration of the event you could use`offHardwareBackButton()` and de-register the event when moving away from the current state.

Example code:

This is the callback

```
var hardwareBackButtonHandler = function() {
  // add you back button logic here
  console.log('Hardware back button pressed');
}
```

Register the back button event like that:

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(hardwareBackButtonHandler);
```

Then when moving away from the current state you can un-register like that:

```
$ionicPlatform.offHardwareBackButton(hardwareBackButtonHandler);
```